# How can I get rid of the max width 1280 without using the wide class in Minimal Mistakes?

Tags: css, sass, jekyll-theme

I'm working on the Jekyll Theme Minimal Mistakes and trying various ways to expand the page. But I'm really trying to get rid of max-width: 1280 which appears when I inspect the page.

I've tried the wide class but I don't want to push the Toc (table of contents) up to the top of the page. In _variables.scss I found the x-large variable set to 1280 but it didn't make a difference when I changed it.

I understand that it is recommended adjusting _page.scss from

```
.page {
  width: calc(100% - #{$right-sidebar-width-narrow});
}
```

to

```
.page {
@include breakpoint($large){
  padding-right: 0;
}
@include breakpoint($x-large){
  padding-right: 0;
}
}
```

When I check the page using the inspection tool there is a piece that pops up showing max-width: 1280. When I uncheck it the page expands the way I want it to but I can't seem to figure out where in the code I can prevent from setting the width to 1280. Is there another calculation other than the one listed above that I should change?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add property to your main.scss file:

```
   $max-width:1440px;
```

Of course, you can specify any value. It will change your main content width and automatically adopt the sidebar and table of content to it.

Comment: I tried `$max-width:100%;` and it is working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I narrowed down the right margin using the below code in `_variable.scss`. Intersting, now I don't have huge margin on the right.

```
$right-sidebar-width-narrow: 100px !default;
$right-sidebar-width: 100px !default;
$right-sidebar-width-wide: 100px !default;
```